# Comparing two given data using plot function of matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, plot, matlab-figure

I recieved a result from my senior which is basically giving alarm if fault is happening. The data is given below:

```
Alarm = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 ...
    3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6 5 4 4 4 4 4 4 3 3 ...
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0];
alarm_test = [ 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
    0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
    0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1];
```

Now I want to plot both in same graph. When I did as you know my result is either 0 or 1 but for above given code is can be highest of 5 so I would like to synchronize the my alarm with given alarm value. For example `alarm_test` 1 would be `Alarm = 3` and likewise so that it can plot in synchronization.  Can anyone help me with that?

I am getting following graph:

[image]

But I want graph like this:

[image]

Comment: _"I want to plot both in same graph"_ - which both? `Alarm` and what?

Comment: I added the the both alarm values. Please have a look !!

Comment: I want to compare graph of both in same plot so that it looks meaningful. but if I plot both values as it is it looks odd as you can see in graph

Comment: If you sum up the values in `alarm_test` you get to 30, but in your illustration it seems that it should accumulate more 'slowly'. Can you explain more clearly what this values a representing? And how they should be synchronized?

Comment: It is just a testing two algorithm, which one of them is detecting fault early. In Alarm is the output given by  another algorithm and Alarm_test is my output (developed by my algorithm). If you figure as it is shown you would easily see that my algorithm detecting system fault much early than given algorithm. But the problem is that the given 'alarm' value increasing value every time for example '3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3' is same but as soon as it reach to '4 4 4 4 4 4' it increase the level. I also want to do the same but in my alarm I have either 1 or 0 not like that. I want such kind of graph !

Comment: Why the `Alarm` is increasing the level? or how do you want to increase yours? should it just accumulate or there is also a way in which it decreases? (I'll post here the accumulation option, so you will see what I mean)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's extremely unclear what are you asking, so maybe some visual examples will help...
You say that your `alarm_test` is only 0 or 1 but you want it to increase (like in the figure you draw). So here is a first suggestion to accumulate the values in `alarm_test`:

```
plot(Alarm)
hold on
plot(cumsum(alarm_test))
hold off
```

[image: try 1]

Now, how far is this then what you look for? and in what?

Comment: It again looks odd. Is it possible to plot properly if we know the time at which we are getting those alarm and then plot like 'Alarm'?

Comment: What do you mean by _properly_? if you want it to be hump-shaped you have to define where it's starts to decrease.